# What is the meaning of 'would' in "I was always told that only time would heal the pain"

Tags: meaning-in-context, lyrics, future-in-the-past

> I was always told that only time
>   **Would** heal the pain (source: #lyrics: until you were gone)

To me it sounds like it is related to willpower
Like she was told that time had potential to heal or the pain or time was capable to heal the pain
But it didnt

Comment: [The Chainsmokers, Tritonal - Until You Were Gone (Audio) ft. Emily Warren](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3FRvZe7sY0U)

Comment: It is called "future in the past". Google for it. (0: The word **would** is used as a past tense form of **will**. It's not related to willpower.

Comment: It is a Future in the Past. The music wants to say that only time can heal the pain.

Comment: See questions tagged [future-in-the-past](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/future-in-past) on ELU.SE, like [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/203458/use-of-would-in-place-of-the-past-simple)

Comment: As @CowperKettle says, this is just the preterit "would". In the present tense, it would (!) be: _"I **am** always told that that only time **will** heal the pain."_